# How to update shared preference string (password) in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

**When application open immateriality will ask password.Initially password is static like(1111). When enter user in Home activity,change the password option is available.Could you please help how to do this...Thanks

```
1. MainActivity.java
String storedPassword = "1111"; 
strPassword=tv_password.getText().toString();
            if(storedPassword.equals(strPassword)) {
                Intent MainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(MainIntent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please check your password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   

2. Homeactivity.java
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button bt_change_password;
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Edit Password");

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 0);
            EditText first_password = new EditText(HomeActivity.this);
            EditText secound_password = new EditText(HomeActivity.this);
            first_password.setHint("new password");
            secound_password.setHint("new password(again)");
            layout.addView(first_password, params);
            layout.addView(secound_password, params);
            alert.setView(layout);
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Problem is resolved...
set Shared Pref:             
             alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    userId= first_password.getText().toString();
                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(HomeActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                    edit.putString("name", userId);
                    edit.commit();
                    }

get shared pref:

SharedPreferences settins = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    strPassword=settins.getString("name", storedPassword);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PrefManager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MY_TAG";
    private static final String PASS_TAG= "my_pass_tag";


 public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

 public void Setpassword(String password) {
        editor.putString(PASS_TAG, password);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public int getpassword() {
        return pref.getString(PASS_TAG);
    }}
```

and then you can use it

```
PrefManager prefManager;
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    String _act = prefManager.getpassword();
    prefManager.setpassword(password)
```

Comment: Thanks for for your reply.                                                Initially password is static in one activity.when we are going to another activity,then i have change pass word.I am going correct way ??in my code???